# Brute-force string manipulation in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, string

Any best algorithm or any brute force method to implement the following things?

1. Find those words are in CAPS.
2. Count number of words in CAPS.
3. Count number of words.
4. Search for exact words.

Cheers,

Venki

Comment: The key thing of "brute force" is basically "try everything", so I doubt that a 'best algorithm' will be anything interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are a good fit for each of these.

Answer (score 0):

Use understandable and maintainable code unless you have special need for performance issues for this task

You could try something like this :

the StringTokenizer  separates your input line into "words" .
you then iterate through them and implement your logic (count, search etc.)

```
int count =0;

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input);
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
   addWordsInCapsToList();
   findSpecificWords();
   count ++;
}
```